# How to find this conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I am struggling with the question below and would appreciate any help.

Let $Z$ be a random variable with a continuous distribution having density
$$
f_{Z}(z)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
2 z & \text { if } 0 \leq z \leq 1 \\
0 & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables, independent given $Z=z$ satisfying
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\mathbf{P}(X=1 \mid Z=z)=z=1-\mathbf{P}(X=0 \mid Z=z)
\end{array}
$$
and
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\mathbf{P}(Y=1 \mid Z=z)=z=1-\mathbf{P}(Y=0 \mid Z=z)
\end{array}
$$
Find the conditional probability
$$
\mathbf{P}(Z \leq 1 / 2 \mid X=1 \text { and } Y=1).
$$

I tried to solve it below:
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{P}(Z \leq 1 / 2 \mid X=1 \text { and } Y=1)\\&=\frac{\mathbf{P}(X=1,Y=1|Z\leq1/2)\mathbf{P}(Z\leq1/2)}{\mathbf{P}(X=1,Y=1|Z\leq1/2)\mathbf{P}(Z\leq1/2)+\mathbf{P}(X=1,Y=1|Z>1/2)\mathbf{P}(Z>1/2)}\\
&=\frac{\mathbf{P}(X=1|Z\leq1/2)\mathbf{P}(Y=1|Z\leq1/2)\mathbf{P}(Z\leq1/2)}{\mathbf{P}(X=1|Z\leq1/2)\mathbf{P}(Y=1|Z\leq1/2)\mathbf{P}(Z\leq1/2)+\mathbf{P}(X=1|Z>1/2)\mathbf{P}(Y=1|Z>1/2)\mathbf{P}(Z>1/2)}\\
&=\frac{\mathbf{P}(X=1|Z\leq1/2)\mathbf{P}(Y=1|Z\leq1/2)1/4}{\mathbf{P}(X=1|Z\leq1/2)\mathbf{P}(Y=1|Z\leq1/2)1/4+\mathbf{P}(X=1|Z>1/2)\mathbf{P}(Y=1|Z>1/2)3/4}\\
\end{align*}
I know $X$ and $Y$ are Bernoulli random variables given $Z$ but I don't know how to proceed from here. I think the right answer is 0.125 based on my simulation.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know how to solve it now,
$$
\begin{array}{l}
P(Z \leq 1 / 2 \mid X=1 \text { and } Y=1) &=\dfrac{P(X=1, Y=1\mid Z \leq 1 / 2 )P(Z \leq 1 / 2 )}{P(X=1,Y=1)}\\
&=\dfrac{\int_0^{1/2}z\cdot z\cdot 2z dz}{\int_0^{1}z\cdot z\cdot 2z dz}\\
&=1/16.
\end{array}
$$